# Add custom event to a CustomControl in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, events, custom-controls, winui-3

I've created a `CustomControl` in **WinUI 3** with some custom properties (`DependencyProperty`).

Now I also want to add a custom `Event` (not sure if it has to be a `RoutedEvent`?) that has to trigger whenever the `CurrentStatus` property of my control changes. I'd like to be able to manage it just like a simple Button's `Click`, so something like:

```cs
public sealed class MyCustomTextBlock : Control
{
    public enum Status
    { 
        Waiting,
        Busy,
    }
    
    private Status currentStatus;
    public Status CurrentStatus
    {
        get { return currentStatus; }
    }

    public MyCustomTextBlock()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomTextBlock);
        currentStatus = Status.Waiting;
    }

    // The currentStatus variable is set on some custom methods inside the implementation of the control.
}
```

```xml
<local:MyCustomTextBlock x:Name="MessageBlock"
                    Message="{TemplateBinding Message}"
                    DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}"
                    StatusChanged="MessageBlock_StatusChanged">
</local:MyCustomTextBlock>
```

```cs
private void MessageBlock_StatusChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check the CurrentStatus property
    if (MyCustomTextBlock.CurrentStatus == MyCustomTextBlock.Status.Waiting)
        // Do something...
}
```

How should I declare the Event and the EventHandler on the code behind of the `MyCustomTextBlock` control?

I'm new to WinUI 3 and XAML and looking for "*winui 3 custom event*" I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event?view=netdesktop-6.0) but it's related to WPF and so I cannot find the `EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent()` which is cited in the WinUI `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` library.

##### Update 2022-09-13

I followed @AndrewKeepCoding suggestion and now this is my code on the `MainWindow` page where I placed `MyCustomTextBlock` control.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <local:MyCustomTextBlock x:Name="MessageBlock"
                             Message="{TemplateBinding Message}"
                             DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}"
                             StatusChanged="MessageBlock_StatusChanged">
    </local:MyCustomTextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void MessageBlock_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustomTextBlock control = (MyCustomTextBlock)sender;
        if (e.NewValue == Status.Waiting)
        {
            // Do something...
        }
        else if (e.NewValue == Status.Busy)
        {
            // Do something else...
        }
    }
}
```

There's no warnings or compilation errors, but now every time I start the application in debug mode it crashes without trapping any specific Exception with the following error description:

> Win32 unmanaged Exception in [10584] WinUI3TestApp.exe

[image: win32 unmanaged exception]

The `MainWindow.InitializeComponent()` method is called without any issue but after passing the last line of the the `public MyCustomTextBlock()` constructor method, I don't know what happens but something makes the app crash.

##### Update 2022-09-14

It seems to be related to this `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5221). There's probably something wrong somewhere inside an async method but it's not possible to catch the Exception due to this bug.

**Workaround**

My problem is related to the Event handler method added in XAML (`StatusChanged="MessageBlock_StatusChanged"`).

After removing it and replacing with the event handler declaration (`MessageBlock.StatusChanged += MessageBlock_StatusChanged;`) in code behind on `MyCustomTextBlock.Loaded()` method, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom `EventHandler` like this.

```cs
public class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Status OldValue { get; }
    public Status NewValue { get; }

    public StatusChangedEventArgs(Status oldValue, Status newValue)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}

public sealed class MyCustomTextBlock : Control
{
    public enum Status
    { 
        Waiting,
        Busy,
    }
    
    private Status currentStatus;
    public Status CurrentStatus
    {
        get { return currentStatus; }
    }

    public MyCustomTextBlock()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomTextBlock);
        currentStatus = Status.Waiting;
    }

    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>? StatusChanged;

    protected void OnStatusChanged(Status oldValue, Status newValue)
    {
        StatusChanged?.Invoke(this, new StatusChangedEventArgs(oldValue, newValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was almost there! Good for me! :-) Anyway, I created all the classes, methods and handler like you did in your code but if I enable the event management on `MyCustomTextBlock` control by adding the `StatusChanged="MessageBlock_StatusChanged"` line in XAML and the corresponding method in code behind, I get a nasty unhandled exception that I'm not able to catch! It seems something crashes... I updated my code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that your code is almost correct but it lacks the coupling between the property `CurrentStatus` and the raise of the event `StatusChanged`. In my code I've added the call to `OnStatusChanged()` on the setter of the property, after having saved the old value.